# I can't set ChomeDriver for Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I try to Start test selenium in Chrome browser. I use Ubuntu 14.04. 
This code doesn't work:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

I was in [the page](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html), I wanted download google driver but this this page is empty!!! I haven't seen any link for downloading. I can't find information which help me.

Answer (score 0):

The latest ChromeDriver version seems to be 2.10, so you should see that directory instead: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded driver. How I can set it? I must add this driver to path or something else?

Comment: Thank you very match for link! I'd put this file in recource directory, written in code  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/chromedriver"); driver = new ChromeDriver(); and all test passed. Maybe you configurated this driver something better?